# org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider provider class was not found

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

Below is the c3p0 configuration m using.

```
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">500</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
        <property name="c3p0.min_size">20</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">60</property>
```

I checked in my log and found
"c3p0 properties were encountered, but the org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider provider class was not found on the classpath; these properties are going to be ignored."

I used 2 lib. c3p0-0.9.1.jar & hibernate-c3p0-4.1.4.final-sources.jar

Please Help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider provider class was not found on the classpath

Because you using hibernate-c3p0-4.1.4.final-**sources**.jar and this jar only contains Java source-code (*.java) files not the compiled Java code (*.class). So even If you are expecting "C3P0ConnectionProvider" class is in your classpath, but in reality it is not.

**Solution**

Use "hibernate-c3p0-4.1.10.Final.jar". This jar contains C3P0ConnectionProvider.class file.

Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks For Your replt Arin.. as u said i removed the sources.jar file and add final.jar now i am getting   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources.pooledDataSource(Ljavax/sql/DataSource;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/sql/DataSource;
 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.configure(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:203)

Comment: Thanks Arin for your support.. I changed the Jar file version... hibernate-c3p0-4.1.9.jar (SAME AS hibernate-core-4.1.9) & 1 more lib. mchange-commons-java-0.2.9.jar and its working fine :)